# Calling method via reflection in Scala

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I want to call an arbitrary public method of an arbitrary stuff via reflection. I.e. let's say, I want to write method `extractMethod` to be used like:

```
class User { def setAvatar(avatar: Avatar): Unit = …; … }

val m = extractMethod(someUser, "setAvatar")
m(someAvatar)
```

From the [Reflection. Overview](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) document from Scala docs, I see the following direct way to do that:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

def extractMethod[Stuff: ClassTag: TypeTag](
  stuff:      Stuff,
  methodName: String): MethodMirror =
  {
    val stuffTypeTag = typeTag[Stuff]
    val mirror = stuffTypeTag.mirror
    val stuffType = stuffTypeTag.tpe
    val methodSymbol = stuffType
      .member(TermName(methodName)).asMethod
    mirror.reflect(stuff)
      .reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
  }
```

However what I'm bothered with this solution is that I need to pass implicit `ClassTag[Stuff]` and `TypeTag[Stuff]` parameters (first one is needed for calling `reflect`, second one — for getting `stuffType`). Which may be quite cumbersome, especially if `extractMethod` is called from generics that are called from generics and so on. I'd accept this as necessity for some languages that strongly lack runtime type information, but Scala is based on JRE, which allows to do the following:

```
def extractMethod[Stuff](
  stuff:          Stuff,
  methodName:     String,
  parameterTypes: Array[Class[_]]): (Object*) => Object =
    {
      val unboundMethod = stuff.getClass()
        .getMethod(methodName, parameterTypes: _*)
      arguments => unboundMethod(stuff, arguments: _*)
    }
```

I understand that Scala reflection allows to get more information that basic Java reflection. Still, here I just need to call a method. Is there a way to somehow reduce requirements (e.g. these `ClassTag`, `TypeTag`) of the Scala-reflection-based `extractMethod` version (without falling back to pure-Java reflection), assuming that performance doesn't matter for me?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is.

1. First, according to [this answer](/a/18730004/1421194), `TypeTag[Stuff]` is a strictly stronger requirement than `ClassTag[Stuff]`. Although we don't automatically get implicit `ClassTag[Stuff]` from implicit `TypeTag[Stuff]`, we can evaluate it manually as `ClassTag[Stuff](stuffTypeTag.mirror.runtimeClass(stuffTypeTag.tpe))` and then implicitly or explicitly pass it to `reflect` that needs it:

   ```
   import scala.reflect.ClassTag
   import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

   def extractMethod[Stuff: TypeTag](
     stuff:      Stuff,
     methodName: String): MethodMirror =
     {
       val stuffTypeTag = typeTag[Stuff]
       val mirror = stuffTypeTag.mirror
       val stuffType = stuffTypeTag.tpe
       val stuffClassTag = ClassTag[Stuff](mirror.runtimeClass(stuffType))
       val methodSymbol = stuffType
         .member(TermName(methodName)).asMethod
       mirror.reflect(stuff)(stuffClassTag)
         .reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
     }
   ```
2. Second, `mirror` and `stuffType` can be obtained from `stuff.getClass()`:

   ```
   import scala.reflect.ClassTag
   import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

   def extractMethod(stuff: Stuff, methodName: String): MethodMirror = {
     val stuffClass = stuff.getClass()
     val mirror = runtimeMirror(stuffClass.getClassLoader)
     val stuffType = mirror.classSymbol(stuffClass).toType
     val stuffClassTag = ClassTag[Stuff](mirror.runtimeClass(stuffType))
     val methodSymbol = stuffType
       .member(TermName(methodName)).asMethod
     mirror.reflect(stuff)(stuffClassTag)
       .reflectMethod(methodSymbol)
   }
   ```

Therefore we obtained Scala-style reflection entities (i.e. finally `MethodMirror`) without requiring `ClassTag` and/or `TypeTag` to be passed explicitly or implicitly from the caller. Not sure, however, how it compares with the ways described in the question (i.e. passing tags from outside and pure Java) in the terms of performance.